# How to render data from fetch api into a table in javscript

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, fetch-api

Im trying to create a table like this

```
<table class="table">
                <thead>
                  <tr>
                    <th scope="col">TokenSymbol</th>
                    <th scope="col">Address</th>
                    <th scope="col">Balance</th>
                  </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                  <tr>
                    <td id="symbol"></td>
                    <td id="address"></td>
                    <td id="balance"></td>
                  </tr>
                  
                </tbody>
              </table>
```

And i want to populate the table with the data from my api call.

The data i get back looks like this:

```
TOAD 0.00084138
chart.js:84 1 0.9
chart.js:84 CWJ 0
chart.js:84 CYN 0
chart.js:84 MOONSTAR 1395658765.4499083
chart.js:84 EMT 0
chart.js:84 DODO 0.06632153
chart.js:84 CWJ 0
chart.js:84 CLIPS 0
chart.js:84 SYRUP 0
chart.js:84 bCORGI 391.66319725
chart.js:84 MONEY 22989070.87819258
chart.js:84 SAFEFAIRMOON 207933.87278968
chart.js:84 1 1
chart.js:84 Cake-LP 0
chart.js:84 Cake 0
chart.js:84 DEFLAX 19304224871.809647
chart.js:84 ORFANO 1360077933.9251838
chart.js:84 BAKE 100
chart.js:84 Long 1.1219391
```

This is the code i use to get this data:

```
fetch(url,opts)
    .then((response) => {
      return response.json();
    })
    .then((data) => {
      const newdata = data;
      const balances = newdata['data']['ethereum']['address'][0];
      
      const symbol = balances['balances'][0]['currency'];
      const value = balances['balances'][0]['value'];
      const bal = balances['balances'];
     // console.log(symbol, value);
      //document.getElementById("tokenBalance").innerHTML = symbol.symbol + "," + symbol.address + "," + value;
    //console.log(bal);
    for(k in bal) { 
        console.log(bal[k].currency.symbol, bal[k].value,bal[k].currency.address); 
        //console.log(bal[k].currency);
        //document.getElementById('symbol').innerHTML = bal[k].currency.address;
        //document.getElementById('address').innerHTML = bal[k].currency.address;
        //document.getElementById('balance').innerHTML = bal[k].value;
    }
      
    });
```

I basically wantt o create a flexible table with the data i posted above, this data can vary, so sometimes the tble would have 5 rows, sometimes 10 rows depending on who calls the function.
So the table has to adjust to this.

How can i solve this with bootstrap and javscript?

Answer (score 0):

You should create a new HTML element, a row in your case, and append it to the table you would like to use. Each new row would be created with the data you want to show, and that would be dynamic depending on your functions.

Either like `var element = document.createElement(tagName[, options]);`

Or you can just document.getElementById('yourTable').append(newRow) where newRow is a new HTML element forged by you with the data you want.

Answer (score 0):

> you have been using the data object. But if you inspect the console your array is inside data.data. So you need to use data.data to iterate over the array like This.

```
 fetch("http://dummy.restapiexample.com/api/v1/employees").then(
  res => {
    res.json().then(
      data => {
        console.log(data.data);
        if (data.data.length > 0) {

          var temp = "";
          data.data.forEach((itemData) => {
            temp += "<tr>";
            temp += "<td>" + itemData.id + "</td>";
            temp += "<td>" + itemData.employee_name + "</td>";
            temp += "<td>" + itemData.employee_salary + "</td></tr>";
          });
          document.getElementById('data').innerHTML = temp;
        }
      }
    )
  }
)

   <div class="container">
    <table class="table">
      <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>Employee Name</th>
        <th>Salary</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="data">

    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```